# Word for the skill of asking good questions

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word like *curious* or *inquisitive*. But those are traits and they seem more... naturally born.

I'm looking for the name of a learned ***skill*** that means that you're good at asking the right questions and analyzing things.

A sample sentence would be:

> We wanted her on our case competition team because she was good at _____.

Comment: Hello, Sritej, you are no stranger here. You should provide some context, and a sample sentence as the SWR tag requires.

Comment: Are you looking for a noun, an adjective, or something else?

Comment: @JasonBassford I was looking for a noun specifically. Jack provided "critical thinking" which I didn't consider at first, but it fits my use case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Critical thinking" is a learned skill.

This is a thorough definition by [The Foundation for Critical Thinking](http://www.criticalthinking.org/pages/our-conception-of-critical-thinking/411):

> Critical thinking is that mode of thinking — about any subject, content, or problem — in which the thinker improves the quality of his or her thinking by skillfully analyzing, assessing, and reconstructing it. Critical thinking is self-directed, self-disciplined, self-monitored, and self-corrective thinking. It presupposes assent to rigorous standards of excellence and mindful command of their use. It entails effective communication and problem-solving abilities, as well as a commitment to overcome our native egocentrism and sociocentrism